# How did Nagato learn about how to create the Paths?

Tags: naruto

I don't know if it was ever explained but, how did Nagato learn about how to create the Paths of Pain?

Answer (score 2):

Obito was responsible for the creation of Akatsuki in it's current state. he manipulated Nagato and those around him and formed the ideas and ideals he needed in Nagato's head. After Yahiko, Nagato's friend and initial leader of Akatsuki died, Nagato gave in to Obito's temptation and it's reasonable to assume Madara explained how the Rinnegan works for Obito to help him resurrect Madara better.

Comment: IIRC, the statement *Obito was responsible for the creation of Akatsuki* is incorrect. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Akatsuki - *Orphans of the Second Shinobi World War, the three created Akatsuki as a way to bring peace to their home country*